# Which mixed model from lme4 to choose if they are not different according to anova function?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am making a `glmer` model to verify how the accuracy in a task varies in function of three other variables: Session Order, Placebo or Experimental group and Type of Trial. In line with visual analysis, the model shows that only the Type of Trial had an effect over accuracy.

I made a few of models in order to verify which one would be a better fit to my data, but, when comparing then using `anova` function, the output is that they are not different from one another. My question is: in this case, how do I choose the best model? Do I stick to the one that best relates to my hypothesis or do I choose the most simple one to keep it parsimonious?

Models:

```
modalidade.lmer.1 <- lme4::glmer(resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade * session
                               + (1|participant), data = stats_modalidade, family = "binomial")
                

modalidade.lmer.2 <- lme4::glmer(resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade + session
                                 + (1|participant), data = stats_modalidade, family = "binomial")
                

modalidade.lmer.3 <- lme4::glmer(resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade
                                 + (1|participant), data = stats_modalidade, family = "binomial")

                
modalidade.lmer.4 <- lme4::glmer(resp_source ~ sham_cat + modalidade
                                 + (1|participant), data = stats_modalidade, family = "binomial")

modalidade.lmer.5 <- lme4::glmer(resp_source ~ modalidade
                                 + (1|participant), data = stats_modalidade, family = "binomial")
```

ANOVA:

```
anova(modalidade.lmer.1, modalidade.lmer.2, modalidade.lmer.3, modalidade.lmer.4, modalidade.lmer.5)
```

ANOVA result:

```
Data: stats_modalidade
Models:
modalidade.lmer.5: resp_source ~ modalidade + (1 | participant)
modalidade.lmer.4: resp_source ~ sham_cat + modalidade + (1 | participant)
modalidade.lmer.3: resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade + (1 | participant)
modalidade.lmer.2: resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade + session + (1 | participant)
modalidade.lmer.1: resp_source ~ sham_cat * modalidade * session + (1 | participant)
                  npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
modalidade.lmer.5    3 6782.9 6802.4 -3388.4   6776.9                     
modalidade.lmer.4    4 6782.5 6808.5 -3387.2   6774.5 2.3865  1     0.1224
modalidade.lmer.3    5 6784.3 6816.9 -3387.2   6774.3 0.1645  1     0.6850
modalidade.lmer.2    6 6786.0 6825.0 -3387.0   6774.0 0.3518  1     0.5531
modalidade.lmer.1    9 6788.8 6847.3 -3385.4   6770.8 3.2031  3     0.3614
```

Comment: "to verify which one would be a better fit to my data" Why are you verifying this? How do you define "better fit"?

Comment: I need to report one model to my results section. That's the purpose. I need to choose one and report the results in the manuscript.

Comment: OK, so this is about inference. Then use the full model, which presumably reflects your planned statistical analysis.

Comment: Tahnk youi, @Roland !